# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command after installing nvm, node and setting path

Tags: nvm

I installed NVM from [the nvm-setup.zip](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
Then, at the command prompt, I ran

```
nvm install 8.11.2
```

Then I ran

```
nvm use 8.11.2
```

which output

```
now using node v8.11.2 (64-bit)
```

Then I ran

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

However when I type

```
node
```

I get

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: What is your OS? Does your `Nodejs` folder contain a `bin` folder?

Comment: Win 10, Program Files\nodejs does not contain bin. Only etc.which is empty,

Comment: Follow below steps:
1. Uninstall all NVM node versions using, NVM uninstall <node-version>
2. Delete folder c:\Program FIles\Nodejs
3. Install node verison using, NVM install <node-version>

now you have "node" command being recognized by command prompt

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I removed the following folders ( kirst being my user name)

```
C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Then I ran the following at the command prompt ( 8.11.2 being the version I wanted)

```
Nvm uninstall 8.11.2
Nvm install 8.11.2
Nvm use 8.11.2
```

Comment: The instructions here helped, but I also had some issues with getting npm to work after the installation. Disabling built-in virus protection was needed to get this working https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/456#issuecomment-723961358

Comment: This worked for me as well, however there is a missing step to reinstall nvm(which is pretty obvious)

Comment: This uninstall an reinstall helped , thank you.

Comment: If uninstall ocmmand does not work, you should manually remove node version folder from nvm in 'C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Roaming\nvm\'.
Then had to relaunch terminal and run 'nvm on' to get node and npm command useable after installing wanted versions.
Thx !

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this issue after installing nvm and node version 16.5.1. FOr anyone who may have a similar issue.

the command **nvm on** solved this for me.

Comment: This worked for me thanks.  It prompted me to use the command "nvm install latest" instead of "nvm install node" per the documentation.

Comment: @Chief I am facing the same issue and this command does not do anything for me. I am using macOS m1. Any idea?

Comment: Well played, this was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Delete C:\Program Files\Nodejs.
Reinstall nvm.
C:\Program Files\Nodejs is recreated and npm and node command work now.

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall the nodejs folder inside the program files

then do nvm use 
now you can use the node and npm commands

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try once `C:\Program Files\Nodejs` with double quotes and close the cmd prompts. Re-open cmd prompts and try once.

Comment: No joy, and the Program Files\nodejs folder is empty except for a folder named etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Uninstall your locally installed `nodejs` and then install node versions thought the NVM.

Answer (score -1):

Just run "nvm use version" without quotes..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).